# Generate form dynamically and submit it by jquery

Tags: jquery

i was searching google just to have way out to generate & submit form by jquery and i found code snippet but few things was not clear to me.

```
function submitValues(url, params) {
var form = [ '<form method="POST" action="', url, '">' ];

for(var key in params) 
    form.push('<input type="hidden" name="', key, '" value="', params[key], '"/>');

form.push('</form>');

jQuery(form.join('')).appendTo('body')[0].submit();
}
```

why [] this third bracket is used like

```
var form = [ '<form method="POST" action="', url, '">' ];
```

what is the meaning of the line **jQuery(form.join('')).appendTo('body')[0].submit();**
why **form.join('')** has been used and why write like **appendTo('body')[0]** why **[0]**

please guide me in detail for those above bold syntax. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By questions order:

1. Brackets `[]` define an array. So in the second line it defines array with three items:

   ```
   var form = [ "first item", "second item", "third item", ... etc ];
   ```
2. `form.join('')` joins all the elements of `form` array with delimiter of empty string, so `form` becomes a string with concatenated substrings from the array.
3. `jQuery(form.join(''))` converts your string into DOM elements and `appendTo("body")` appends these elements (`<form><input> ... </form>`) inside `body`.
4. Using `[0]` you get your `form`, however not as a jQuery object but as DOM element. Native `form` element has method `submit` which is called with `.submit()`.

For any doubts with native JavaScript methods and functions you can read [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide). jQuery documentation is provided at [**api.jquery.com**](http://api.jquery.com/).

Comment: Note that the `[0]` is not actually necessary, as jQuery also defines a `$.submit()` method which functions in the same manner as the native DOM method. You're also guaranteed that the jQuery object only contains one node, as you constructed your HTML to only include a single `<form>` element.

Comment: this point is not clear :- Using [0] you get your form, however not as a jQuery object but as DOM element. Native form element has method submit which is called with .submit().  if possible plzz elaborate with few more samples.

Comment: @Thomas Sure! It works the same as [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method in jQuery. As written in the linked doc, it *grants us access to the DOM nodes underlying each jQuery object*. So, as you should already know, jQuery object and DOM element are different things. For example, `var el = $("#myID");` and `var el = document.getElementById("myID");` address the same element, but the first will return jQuery object, and the second DOM node.

Answer (score 1):

1. The [] brackets means that form is an array.
2. The [Array.join](http://w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) method concatenates all strings in the array to one large string. In your code, this becomes the form html markup.
3. [appendTo('body')](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) method, appends the form-html to the body of your document, and returns the jquery selector.
4. Because a jQuery selector can point to multiple elements (it is an array), you need to specify that it is the first element you want to submit. Therefor the [0].

Comment: Why not? Does the W3schools article say anything wrong about the Array.join() function? Do you have any alternatives you can recommend?

Comment: You can have a look at [W3Fools](http://w3fools.com/). At the moment MDN is the best alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the explanation for few of your doubts.

1. By wrapping in a square elements like `[ '<form method="POST" action="', url, '">' ]` It becomes an array.
2. `form.join('')` This will join the form array which was created by using the `.push()` method.
3. When we use [0] for jQuery selector it becomes a node from jQuery object. Where in we can use normal javascript operation.
4. `.appendTo('body')` this will append the content to the body element.

Comment: this point is not clear :- Using [0] you get your form, however not as a jQuery object but as DOM element. Native form element has method submit which is called with .submit().  if possible plzz elaborate with few more samples.

Comment: I think this article will help you to understand. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942193/whats-the-difference-between-a-jquery-object-and-a-dom-element-difference-betw