# Javascript:unable to get element by id

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a java-script code which print the `post to fb wall` link and call a `PostToWall` Javascript function on click, in this function i am trying to read data under `span` by its id.  But unfortunately its not returning the span data
.Please help me to solve my problem.

First: this code prints on my html page after a certain JS function is called
 `$('#content').html('<h1>You\'re done</h1><br/><a href="#" onclick="return postToWall();"> Share your score in FACEBOOK</a>\n`

Second: Users click on the "Share your ...FB" then it calls this function:

```
function postToWall() {
  var msg = document.getElementById("timespent"); alert(msg);
  ------ 
 }
```

It is callin func but its not showing the data under under `span id=timespent`

where `<span id="timespent" style="zoom: 80%" class="timeisplay">4732</span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put the `timespent` span object in alert instead of its html. You need to using `innerHTML` to show the html with span

```
alert(msg.innerHTML);
```

Comment: yes now its fine. But in jquery there is no need to put like this `innerHtml` why in javascript?  In jquery simply `$("timespent").html();`

Comment: jQuery has function html but javascript COM object does not have it. If you have DOM object you should try using native properties. It will give you performance benefits

Comment: thanks, but what do you mean by `If you have DOM object you should try using native properties.`  ?

Comment: Reading this will help understand what DOM and jQuery are and how they differ. JQuery is wrapper over javascript but jQuery is usually slower then javascript

Comment: `Reading this` but what? I think you forget to attach link in your previous comment.-:)

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, here we go, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942193/whats-the-difference-between-a-jquery-object-and-a-dom-element-difference-betw

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Try in jQuery.

```
alert($('#timespent').text());
```