# What are the differences between jquery objects and javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can any one explain about the differences among the javascript objects and jquery objects with suitable example and dissection of the example?

Comment: There is no difference; a jQuery object is a Javascript object, it just contains a defined set of properties.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942193/whats-the-difference-between-a-jquery-object-and-a-dom-element-difference-betw

Comment: It sounds like a school work. But i guess/hope no because this question honestly doesn't really make sense

Comment: @AnoopJoshi That's not really a duplicate as it's about a jQuery object vs a DOMElement.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ohh. got it. Reopened it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I could be wrong but i think this is what means OP too regrading dupe, refering to a DOM node, not really a javascript object.

Comment: @A.Wolff you could well be right. This question is very vague as to what answer the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A JavaScript object is a collection of data wrapped up into a single "thing".

A jQuery object is a JavaScript object which is the *particular* collection of data you get when you call the `jQuery` function with one of the sets of arguments that populates it with DOM nodes.

Comment: can you explain with a example.Am new to this stuff

Comment: The first part of learning is knowing how to research yourself. This answer is about as succinct as it can be as the question itself is very broad.

Comment: @tom_boy — A jQuery object *is* an example of a JavaScript object.

Comment: tq @Quentin..I understood it