# ckeditor : "this.$.nodeName is undefined" error (from ckeditor.js), inline editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am new to this ckeditor.
So, I was trying out something very simple. I want to inline edit this p element.

```
<p class="h_text" >is your site working?</p>
```

So, I have this script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;                

            var elementToEdit = $("body").find("p.h_text").first();
            console.log($(elementToEdit).length);
            console.log($(elementToEdit).html());                
            $(elementToEdit).attr('contenteditable', 'true');

            CKEDITOR.inline(elementToEdit);
        });
```

When I load the page I get this error thrown from ckeditor.js

```
TypeError: this.$.nodeName is undefined
```

From the 2 console.log output, I can confirm that the elementToEdit is valid and not null.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by changing this line in script

```
CKEDITOR.inline(elementToEdit);
```

to this

```
$(elementToEdit).ckeditor();
```

To be honest, I did not quite understand why this works and the first one does not. 
It would be helpful if anyone explains this.

Comment: That means `CKEDITOR.inline()` expects a DOM node (i guess because i've never used this plugin), not a jq object. So it should be `elementToEdit.each(function(){CKEDITOR.inline(this);});`. And FYI, `elementToEdit` is already a jq object, your code should be just: `elementToEdit.ckeditor();`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942193/whats-the-difference-between-a-jquery-object-and-a-dom-element-difference-betw    BTW, `$(elementToEdit).attr('contenteditable', 'true');` should be `elementToEdit.prop('contenteditable', true);` if you use any jq version >= 6

Comment: thanks for the comment. Just to add, in case it helps anyone, my original code will also work like this CKEDITOR.inline($(elementToEdit).get(0));

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var elementToEdit = $("body").find("p.h_text")[0];
```

instead of this,

```
var elementToEdit = $("body").find("p.h_text").first();
```