# Is it possible load datatable with javascript

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am trying to load datatable using with javascript(not jQuery).

Here is sample:

```
var dc_table = document.getElementById('dc-table');

dc_table.dataTable({options....});
```

But when try this getting this error:

```
TypeError: dc_table.dataTable is not a function
```

How can we do this with javascript?

Thanks

Comment: are you using the datatables jquery plugin?

Comment: Do you mean `document` has no function `getElementById`?

Comment: If wonder if you've overwritten document or have a local variable with the name document

Comment: @kodcu then u need jquery. i think the error is most likely that dataTable is not a function

Comment: I edited question .Please take a look at again

Answer (score 0):

Since [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) is a jQuery plugin, jQuery is a required dependency for the [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) plugin. Also, a DOM object will not have a  function called `DataTable()` associated with it.

```
document.getElementById('dc-table')
```

returns a DOM object and will not have a function called `DataTable()` associated with it. Only a jQuery object will.

```
$("#dc-table")
```

will have a `DataTable()` function

[The jQuery object representing a DOM element and the DOM object are not the same.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942193/whats-the-difference-between-a-jquery-object-and-a-dom-element-difference-betw)